# Creating ranks for the elements in array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So here is the problem:

> Create the ranks for the given numeric array a.
> Hint: You can use `np.rank()` method

```
# Input
#> [ 9  4 15  0 17 16 17  8  9  0]

# Output

#> [4 2 6 0 8 7 9 3 5 1]
```

And I found this solution

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(10)
a = np.random.randint(20, size=10)
print(a.argsort().argsort())
```

But I can't understand why does it work.

Comment: *"Hint: You can use `np.rank()` method"*  You probably already noticed that `np.rank` does not exist.  The function [`scipy.stats.rankdata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rankdata.html) ranks data, with a variety of options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When random seed is defined as 10, random integer function returns original input array. `argsort()` function returns an array of indices arranged to sort original array in ascending order. So when `argsort()` is executed only once it returns following output.

```
print(a.argsort())
[3 9 1 7 0 8 2 5 4 6]
```

This list shows indices of elements to sort original array. When you choose elements as `a.argsort()` function shows, you will get sorted version of the original array as follows.

```
print(a[3], a[9], a[1], a[7], a[0], a[8], a[2], a[5], a[4], a[6])
0 0 4 8 9 9 15 16 17 17
```

When `argsort()` function is applied to secondary array `[3 9 1 7 0 8 2 5 4 6]`, it will show rank of each element.

For example in original array first element is 9. When you apply `argsort()` first time, it puts index of that element, which is 0, at a position where index is 4. Because it is the 5th smallest element in original array. When you apply `argsort()` again, final output will generated. This element becomes first element of final output because secondary array stores its index. And its value will be 4 because its index in secondary array was 4.

To sum up, values of secondary array show indexes of elements to sort original array. In the meantime, its order shows rank of each element in original array implicitly. When second `argsort()` is applied, this implicit information come up. It generates an array that shows rank of each element in original array.